# After updating to Java SE 8u31 release, after the update Eclipse Will Not Run

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I just updated my java to the new Java SE 8u31. I have eclipse for android installed on my computer. Now when i try and start eclipse.exe it will not run/ open or execute. Is anyone facing a similar problem, and if you have solved it, how did you got about solving it.

Comment: Do you get any messages? If so what?

Comment: I don't get any message. It doesn't show any message.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have faced this problem when i passed from java 7 to java 8 but the Eclipse shown me that no Java exist in my pc(think that the same bug).

I will give you a webpage that i reinstall the java(it's not the best solution
but give a try) unistall completely java and install it from here [this page](https://ninite.com/)

1.In developer tools select JDK(32 or 64)

2.In Runtime select Java

That worked for me when i had this problem

Let me know if that works for you...

Comment: Yes this works. However the solution i found was to actually delete the new Java 8 update, its not compatible with eclipse.